# Simple if-clause not working, can't find the mistake

Tags: java, android, oop, if-statement

So I am working on an incremental game at the moment. In case you don't know what this is a short explanation. You click a button to get some kind of money (in my case gold). With enough money you can buy stuff that makes you money without even clicking. With more money you can get better upgrades which makes you even more money and so on.

Now to my problem; I created a class called `Upgrade` which you can see here:

```
public class Upgrade {
    double baseCost;
    double baseIncome;
    int count =0;
    double cost = baseCost*Math.pow(1.07,count);
    double goldPerSecond = baseIncome; //TODO find usefull formula!

    public Upgrade(double baseC, double baseIn){
        baseCost = baseC;
        baseIncome = baseIn;
    }
}
```

The variables should explain themselves.

Now I created some `Upgrade`s via the constructor:

```
Upgrade waitress = new Upgrade(50 ,2); //Constructor for Waitress
Upgrade seats = new Upgrade(100, 5);   //Constructor for More-Seats
Upgrade decoration = new Upgrade(500, 20); //Constructor for Decoration 
Upgrade bartender = new Upgrade (1000, 50); //Constructor for Bartender
```

To buy upgrades I have written the method `buyUpgrade` which is bound to buttons referring to the upgrades listed above.

```
public void buyUpgrade(Upgrade U) {
    if (goldCount >= U.cost) {
        goldCount = goldCount - U.cost;
        clickGoldPerSecond++;
        U.count++;
    } else {
        error.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_gold));
    }
}
```

And here comes the problem. As the game starts you have 0 gold. That 0 is stored in the variable `goldCount`. But even though `goldCount` is I can buy every `Upgrade` in unlimited amounts. I just cant figure out the problem. Probably it is really simple and afterwards I realize how stupid I was but I just cant figure it out.

Every help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Think about what value `baseCost` has when you're determining the upgrade's `cost`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
int count =0;
double cost = baseCost*Math.pow(1.07,count); // cost is set and will not be updated
```

Pls note that you update baseCost in your constructor, but before that the default value 0.0 is being used for `baseCost * Math.pow(...);`. But even if you update that, by having it done in the constructor, still you will not see any price going up, because the cost is not being recalculated at all.

- Set the initial value in the constructor (or have `baseCost` always being added to the cost when accessing the cost).
- Make a method which adds one to `count` and then does `Math.pow(...)` on `cost` again.

Now for a much better solution: hence, in this case the attribute cost is useless. Change it into a method:

```
public double getCost() {
    return baseCost*Math.pow(1.07,count);
}
```

call it (change 2x `U.cost` --> `U.getCost()`) and your sky will be blue again, no further change needed where ever.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing getter/setter for cost i guess. Therefore it always return 0.0.

I mean try to create an Upgrade object with the constructor, then print out the cost. No matter what you give in the constructor, the cost for the object always print out "0.0".

Comment: I updated my answer too :) but you still suggest make a method which adds one to count :) thats unnecessary. There is nothing wrong with the formula he just doesn't set cost the app gets the default value 0.0 everytime.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
double baseCost;
double baseIncome;
int count =0;
double cost = baseCost*Math.pow(1.07,count);
```

baseCost being the member variable of the class, is intialized to 0.0 
SO "cost" set to 0.0 and it never changed after that.

You should move the cost calculation in the constructor.

```
public Upgrade(double baseC, double baseIn){
    baseCost = baseC;
    baseIncome = baseIn;
    cost = baseCost*Math.pow(1.07,count);
}
```

Comment: Still then it works for the first, but the cost never gets updated

Comment: cost is supposed to be updated only once. goldCount is decreasing by the cost each time .

Comment: baseCost  is set to zero ... zero * any number is zero :-)

Comment: I think the price has to rise up when you buy an item... So only the constructor does not help enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Upgrade 
{
 double baseCost;
 double baseIncome;
 int count =0;
 double cost ;
 double goldPerSecond;

 public Upgrade(double baseC, double baseIn)
{
     baseCost = baseC;
     cost = baseCost * Math.Pow(1.07,count);
     baseIncome = baseIn;
 }
}

Your Upgrade class should be similar to what I have created here. If there is a non static filed in the class and you are assigning value to that variable in the way you were doing it will not work.

In your case you also cannot use the static variable as the variable baseCost is passed as constructor parameter and will not be available until you create an instance of upgrade class.

If Condition if(goldCount >= U.cost){} Here the cost will have value of zero only as it would not get updated.
```

Comment: Still then it works for the first, but the cost never gets updated